# Variables and math operators

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Strange javascript addition problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416633/strange-javascript-addition-problem)

I know there's obviously a solution for this, and I've done it before, but I can't remember it and now I can't find it.

```
​<div>1</div>​​​​​​​​

$(function() {
    var number = $('div').text();
    var math = number + 2;
    $('body').text(math);
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/G5zdx/

`number` is not being treated as an integer so `math`'s value is "12" instead of "3". How can I correct this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways, but

```
var math = (1 * number) + 2;
```

is a simple one. Whether you should be detecting possible ill-formed non-numbers depends on the nature of the rest of your code.

The `parseInt()` function is useful, but it probably should be called with 10 as its second argument to avoid interpreting numbers that begin with zero as octal constants instead of decimal. Also, `parseInt()` will not treat a string like "23skidoo" as an error, which may or may not be OK in your application.

Answer (score 2):

```
​<div>1</div>​​​​​​​​

$(function(){
  var number = parseInt($('div').text(), 10);
  var math = number+2;
  $('body').text(math);
});​
```

Comment: It's always a good idea to pass 10 as the second argument to `parseInt()`, because otherwise it will interpret numbers that begin with a 0 character as octal instead of decimal.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse a string as an int using `parseInt(string[, radix])`.

Your code would look as follows

```
$(function(){
  var number = $('div').text();
  var math = parseInt(number, 10)+2;
  $('body').text(math);
});
```

Source: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/convert2.htm